# React 404 when attempting to call a URL only in production

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404

In development I have a React website which makes calls directly to an API hosted on Digital Ocean.

The main url is `http://localhost:3000` and loads perfectly well. This contains a series of links all of which redirect to a variation of `http://localhost:3000/narrative/[id]` such as `http://localhost:3000/narrative/4265` or `http://localhost:3000/narrative/1`.

If I attempt, on development, a reload of `http://localhost:3000/narrative/4265` then the page reloads absolutely fine. Similarly, if I open a tab or new browser window and go directly to `http://localhost:3000/narrative/4265` the page loads fine.

On production however, I get a 404 both when reloading the page or attempting to navigate to it from a new tab or window.

I've seen the below questions:

- [How to handle 404 in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548482/how-to-handle-404-in-react). I don't think this applies as my instance works fine on development
- [React Router Gives 404 error on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770865/react-router-gives-404-error-on-production). I'm not too sure how to configure htaccess (if I can put it in the deployable repo or if I have to configure direct on the server), or indeed how to *"configure a single entry point"* as another answer suggests.

I see from @jonsharpe answer [See Building for relative paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) that it's possible to use `BrowserRouter` on my index.js. However I'm not sure that I should be modifying the `Route` for `Link`

```
  <HashRouter>
    <Navigation />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
            <Route path="/narrative/:id" element={<Detail />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>

  </HashRouter>
```

Comment: The details of how to configure your web server will depend on _what your web server is_. See e.g. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment (or even https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration, this isn't specific to React and is needed for any SPA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding `--spm` to the `pm2 serve build 80` command

And the suggestion was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67987377/1249379)

Comment: did you mean --spa?